# Excel crashes when running a macro that loops through several files

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have created a macro that opens few files and copies data from that files into one workbook. The way macro works is:
1) There is a main workbook (target workbook) with few worksheets, one of the worksheets contains paths to the files in the column B. Cells F1 and H1 contains two subfolders that users specify and these two cells are added into the file path. Files are named differently, but all the files contain "One pager" in the name. So I use a file path and a wild card "One pager*" & ".xlsx" to open the file.
2) Macro checks how many rows are filled with a path and loops through the rows with paths, opens each files (source workbook), copies specified fields into target worksheet in the main workbook and then closes source files.

Macro works fine when I run it step by step or when I set a break point and run one loop at a time, but as soon as I run complete macro my Excel crashes after running through 5-6 files. I tried to run the same macro on 4 different computers, on two of them excel crashes while running macro, on two of them macro works fine. Two computers where macro crashes run windows 8.1 64bit professional and two where macro works fine run windows 7 64 and 32bit enterprise and all computers have Office 365. Could someone have a look into code, maybe there is somethign I can optimise to make it work on all computers?
Thank you in advance

```
    Private Sub GenerateReportOP()
    Dim ThisWB As Workbook
    Dim OnePager As Workbook
    Dim ThisMacro As Worksheet
    Dim ThisOnePage As Worksheet
    Dim OnePagerWS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim LastRowZ As Long
    Dim LastRowMOP As Long
    Dim OPPath As String
    Dim BSpath As String
    Dim Rates As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SubstrinLoc As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Set ThisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ThisMacro = ThisWB.Sheets("Macros")
    Set ThisOnePage = ThisWB.Sheets("One Pagers")

    ThisOnePage.Cells.Clear
    LastRowMOP = ThisMacro.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    i = 3
    Do While i <= LastRowMOP
    LastRow1 = ThisOnePage.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ThisMacro.Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
    ThisOnePage.Range("B" & LastRow1 + 1) = ThisMacro.Range("A" & i)
    ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = "FX:"
    'just formating section
    ThisOnePage.Range("B" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Bold = True
    ThisOnePage.Range("B" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
    ThisOnePage.Range("B" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Size = 14
    ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Bold = True
    ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
    ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Size = 14
    'Define one pager workbook
    OPPath = ThisMacro.Range("B" & i) & ThisMacro.Range("F1") & "\" & ThisMacro.Range("H1") & "\"
    'error handler if path is not correct
    On Error GoTo Error_handler:
    Set OnePager = Workbooks.Open(OPPath & "*One Pager*" & ".xlsx")
    Set OnePagerWS = OnePager.Worksheets("Check list")
    LastRow2 = OnePagerWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowZ = OnePagerWS.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'check what ratees is linked
    Rates = OnePagerWS.Range("S8").Formula
    SubstrinLoc = InStr(1, Rates, "FY")
    ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1) = Mid(Rates, SubstrinLoc + 6, 13)
    ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Bold = True
    ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
    ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Size = 14
    'copy one pager
    OnePagerWS.Range("D4").Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("I" & LastRow1 + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("I" & LastRow1 + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("A6:A" & LastRow2).Copy Destination:=ThisOnePage.Range("B" & LastRow1 + 2)
    OnePagerWS.Range("J6:J" & LastRow2).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("L6:L" & LastRow2).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("N6:N" & LastRow2).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("E" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("E" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow2).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("F" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("F" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("S6:S" & LastRow2).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("G" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("G" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("T6:T" & LastRow2).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("H" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("H" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    OnePagerWS.Range("Z" & LastRowZ).Copy
    ThisOnePage.Range("I" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisOnePage.Range("I" & LastRow1 + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    LastRow2 = ThisOnePage.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With ThisOnePage
        .Range(.Cells(LastRow1 + 4, 1), .Cells(LastRow2, 1)) = ThisMacro.Range("A" & i)
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    OnePager.Close savechanges:=False

    'error handler if path is not correct
Error_handler:
        If ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1) = "" Then
            ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = "Unable to find One Pager, please check file or path!"
        End If
        Resume Next
    End If

    i = i + 1
    Loop
    ThisOnePage.Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    MsgBox "Finished. Please check ""One Pagers"" tab."
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the problem, but your error handler code should be outside the main body of the procedure - between  `Exit Sub` and `End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your help. I combined two advices of Darren and S Maeden.
I changed my error handler and made macro to copy data direcly into cells avoiding usage of clipboard. I'm just working on formating part now

```
OPPath = ThisMacro.Range("B" & i) & ThisMacro.Range("F1") & "\" & ThisMacro.Range("H1") & "\"
        'error handler if path is not correct
        On Error Resume Next
        Set OnePager = Workbooks.Open(OPPath & "*One Pager*" & ".xlsx")
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            If ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1) = "" Then
                ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = "Unable to find One Pager, please check file or path!"
            End If
        Else
            Set OnePagerWS = OnePager.Worksheets("Check list")
            LastRow2 = OnePagerWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LastRowZ = OnePagerWS.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            'check what rates is linked
            Rates = OnePagerWS.Range("S9").Formula
            SubstrinLoc = InStr(1, Rates, "FY")
            ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1) = Mid(Rates, SubstrinLoc + 6, 13)
            ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Bold = True
            ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
            ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Font.Size = 14
            'copy one pager
            ThisOnePage.Range("I" & LastRow1 + 2).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("D4").Value

            ThisOnePage.Range("B" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":B" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("A6:A" & LastRow2).Value

            ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":C" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("J6:J" & LastRow2).Value
            ThisOnePage.Range("C" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":C" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).NumberFormat = "0"
            ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":D" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("L6:L" & LastRow2).Value
            ThisOnePage.Range("D" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":C" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).NumberFormat = "0"
            ThisOnePage.Range("E" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":E" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("N6:N" & LastRow2).Value

            ThisOnePage.Range("F" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":F" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow2).Value

            ThisOnePage.Range("G" & LastRow1 + 2 & ":G" & LastRow1 + LastRow2 - 4).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("S6:S" & LastRow2).Value

            ThisOnePage.Range("H" & LastRow1 + 2).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("T6:T" & LastRow2).Value

            ThisOnePage.Range("J" & LastRow1 + 2).Value = OnePagerWS.Range("Z" & LastRowZ).Value

            LastRow2 = ThisOnePage.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            With ThisOnePage
                .Range(.Cells(LastRow1 + 4, 1), .Cells(LastRow2, 1)) = ThisMacro.Range("A" & i)
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            OnePager.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    End If

    i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: `Application.CutCopyMode = False` made all the difference to me. I wasn't copying anything, just dealing with a bunch of files, and after I included this line, Excel stopped crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Excel should not crash but in the real world it does if you push it.  Instead of running experiments I'd rewrite the code to make it safer.

So how to make your code safer.  Well, I'm guessing that perhaps you problem is you are thrashing the clipboard with your copy and pastes.  I almost never have copy and paste code in production.  If I want to copy cells from source to destination then I use the Range.Value2 bulk get/set.  So an example would be

```
Range("Destination").Value2 = Range("Source").Value2
```

You need to make sure the source and destination ranges are of exact same dimension.  So swap in this type of code for your copy and paste values.
Also, format the cells with VBA code rather than copying from clipboard.

See if that fixes it.  Post feedback.

Comment: while you have a point, I recon he still has to use `.Copy` to copy the formats.

Comment: @Martin Dreher: yeah, possibly, I am zealot about some things. :) Hello to Freiburg, good place for cycling and ordoliberalism.

Comment: @S Meaden: true, but still a terrible place for finding a job... ;)

Answer (score 0):

@S Meaden is right in the regard that you should try to avoid `.Copy` + `.Paste` when possible.

However, since you want the formats, I guess this is actually one of the rare cases where copy+pasting makes sense.

I recon your problem is not the `.Copy` per se, but rather the repeated `.Open` + `.Close` of the OnePager-workbooks.

When I encountered a similar problem, my Excel didn't exactly crash, the macro just stopped randomly without triggering the error handler.

I would try the following:

- open a new Excel before entering the loop
- open your OnePager-files with that app, and paste into your existing Excel

Hope that helps!

Here's how you can adjust your code:

```
Private Sub GenerateReportOP()

    '... your code

    ' open a new Excel in which you open the files
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    i = 3
    Do While i <= LastRowMOP

        '... your code

        ' change: repeatedly open the files in your new excel app
        Set OnePager = xlApp.Workbooks.Workbooks.Open(OPPath & "*One Pager*" & ".xlsx")

        '... your code

        xlApp.CutCopyMode = False
        OnePager.Close savechanges:=False

        '... your code

    i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' close the new excel after you're done looping. always close it (w/ errorhandler), so you dont have to shut it down with the task manager
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    '... your code

    MsgBox "Finished. Please check ""One Pagers"" tab."
End Sub
```

Also, reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) should speed up your coding quite a bit an will likely make your code more readable